# mkfs.vfat can't find the first partition on my disk

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, mkfs, vfat

I wanted to install `Arch` `Linux` on my `Raspberry Pi 3` and I found [this](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3)  tab[Installation] article that describes the process step-by step: Now, I've run into a problem when I tried to create the `vfat` fs on the first partition:
My partition table:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0p7: 28.4 GiB, 30438064128 bytes, 59449344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x11a5fc51

Device           Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p7p1        2048   206847   204800  100M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7p2      206848 59449343 59242496 28.3G 83 Linux
```

but still:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# mkfs.vfat /dev/mmcblk0p7p1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/mmcblk0p7p1: No such file or directory
```

Why is this and how can I get around it?

Comment: Did you try to make the partitions from scratch after reformatting it?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, I created the two partitions according to https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3  tab [Installation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install Arch inside partition 7 of your SD card.

What you have done is to create two partitions inside that one partition. The `fdisk` utility has assumed that `/dev/mmcblk0p7` is the SD Card (whereas it's actually just a partition on the SD Card) and derived the two partition names from it, `/dev/mmcblk0p7p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p7p2`. These won't exist so you can't reference them.

In case there's any confusion, the canonical name for your SD Card itself is `/dev/mmcblk0`.

Comment: very true, that worked fine but it wouldn't let me write the ew partition table because it's mounted so my work around idea is to boot some other Linux from USB and change my partition table when running from usb....

Comment: @stdcerr if you do that you will **erase everything** on the SD Card. It's beginning to sound to me that this is not what you intend.

Comment: Yes, do a clean sweep and then install Arch on it.